# Decoding json (containig encoded like \u003c HTML entities) with json_decode, unexpected result

Tags: php, json

Trying to decode this json:

```
$json = '{"d":{"results":[{"__metadata":{"uri":"https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Bing/Search/Composite?Sources=\u0027web+spell+relatedsearch\u0027&Query=\u0027\"\u003e\u003c/a\u003e\u003cimg src=\"&$skip=0&$top=1#\"\u003e\u003cscript\u003ealert(\u00273\u0027);\u003c/script\u003e\"\u0027&Market=\u0027it-IT\u0027&Adult=\u0027Strict\u0027&Options=\u0027DisableLocationDetection+EnableHighlighting\u0027&WebSearchOptions=\u0027DisableQueryAlterations\u0027","type":"ExpandableSearchResult"},"ID":"5afc1ab9-f4a7-43e1-9d14-dbec42f83c0c","WebTotal":"4","WebOffset":"0","ImageTotal":"","ImageOffset":"","VideoTotal":"","VideoOffset":"","NewsTotal":"","NewsOffset":"","SpellingSuggestionsTotal":"","AlteredQuery":"","AlterationOverrideQuery":"","Web":[{"__metadata":{"uri":"https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Bing/Search/ExpandableSearchResultSet(guid\u00275afc1ab9-f4a7-43e1-9d14-dbec42f83c0c\u0027)/Web?$skip=0&$top=1","type":"WebResult"},"ID":"38cc61c8-4ce2-4013-92ee-a2fa4de3abcc","Title":"apache 2.2.21 exploits - Page 2 - Code Exploits Collection","Description":"... script\u003e password_verify \"\u003e\u003cscript\u003ealert(2);\u003c/script\u003e firstname \"\u003e\u003cscript\u003ealert(3);\u003c/script ... 703F67657470776E65643D: Administrators\u003c/a\u003e\u003cimg src=\"http://192.168.0.15/learn ...","DisplayUrl":"exploitsdownload.com/search/apache%202.2.21/2","Url":"http://exploitsdownload.com/search/apache%202.2.21/2"},{"__metadata":{"uri":"https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Bing/Search/ExpandableSearchResultSet(guid\u00275afc1ab9-f4a7-43e1-9d14-dbec42f83c0c\u0027)/Web?$skip=1&$top=1","type":"WebResult"},"ID":"df1b6d37-efc1-4d3c-bed5-7d6e34a3d686","Title":"siteniz için htlm kodları - Sayfa 3 - Baktabul Forum","Description":"... gelecek ve sooon\") \u003c/script\u003e \u003cscript\u003e alert(\"4!!\") \u003c/script\u003e \u003cscript\u003e alert(\"3!!!\") \u003c/script\u003e \u003cscript\u003e ... BURAYA YAZIN!!!\u0027,500,300); return false\" \u003e \u003e\u003e\u003eGİRİŞ \u003c\u003c\u003c\u003c\u003c/a\u003e \u003cIMG SRC= \"http ...","DisplayUrl":"www.baktabul.net/webmaster/42351-siteniz-icin-htlm-kodlari-3.html","Url":"http://www.baktabul.net/webmaster/42351-siteniz-icin-htlm-kodlari-3.html"},{"__metadata":{"uri":"https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Bing/Search/ExpandableSearchResultSet(guid\u00275afc1ab9-f4a7-43e1-9d14-dbec42f83c0c\u0027)/Web?$skip=2&$top=1","type":"WebResult"},"ID":"fab98f52-bbe6-40f7-805d-5ab14b503827","Title":"php 5.2.17 exploits - Page 1 - Code Exploits Collection","Description":"... trace_results.php?product_id=117&amp;project_id=40&amp;funder=31\"\u003e\u003cscript\u003ealert(3);\u003c/script ... 703F67657470776E65643D: Administrators\u003c/a\u003e\u003cimg src=\"http://192.168.0.15/learn ...","DisplayUrl":"exploitsdownload.com/search/php%205.2.17","Url":"http://exploitsdownload.com/search/php%205.2.17/"},{"__metadata":{"uri":"https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Bing/Search/ExpandableSearchResultSet(guid\u00275afc1ab9-f4a7-43e1-9d14-dbec42f83c0c\u0027)/Web?$skip=3&$top=1","type":"WebResult"},"ID":"82b3c849-4cdc-409a-95a8-a74310b723aa","Title":"DEV ARŞİV \u0027\u0027Hazır kodlar\u0027ın %90 burada\u0027\u0027 İçeri buyrun\u003e\u003e\u003e","Description":"... ve sooon\")\u003c/script\u003e \u003cscript\u003ealert(\"4!!\")\u003c/script\u003e \u003cscript\u003ealert(\"3!!!\")\u003c/script ... BURAYA YAZIN!!!\u0027,500,300); return false\"\u003e\u003e\u003e\u003eGİRİŞ\u003c\u003c\u003c\u003c\u003c/a\u003e\u003cIMG SRC=\"http ...","DisplayUrl":"www.zevkli.org/dev-ar350304v-haz305r-kodlar305n-90-burada-304231...","Url":"http://www.zevkli.org/dev-ar350304v-haz305r-kodlar305n-90-burada-304231eri-buyrungtgtgt-t180384.html"}],"Image":[],"Video":[],"News":[],"RelatedSearch":[],"SpellingSuggestions":[]}]}}';
```

php returned to me using `var_dump(json_decode($jsonOriginalResults, true));`

a wrong array with \u003c characters decoded, but why?

I just expect a result like this:

```
array(1) {
  ["d"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["results"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(19) {
        ["__metadata"]=>
        array(2) {
          ["uri"]=>
          string(403) "https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Bing/Search/Composite?Sources=\u0027web+spell+relatedsearch\u0027&Query=\u0027"\u003e\u003c/a\u003e\u003cimg src="&=0&=1#"\u003e\u003cscript\u003ealert(\u00273\u0027);\u003c/script\u003e"\u0027&Market=\u0027it-IT\u0027&Adult=\u0027Strict\u0027&Options=\u0027DisableLocationDetection+EnableHighlighting\u0027&WebSearchOptions=\u0027DisableQueryAlterations\u0027"
          ["type"]=>
          string(22) "ExpandableSearchResult"
        }
        ["ID"]=>
        string(36) "5afc1ab9-f4a7-43e1-9d14-dbec42f83c0c"
        ["WebTotal"]=>
        string(1) "4"
        ["WebOffset"]=>
        string(1) "0"
        ["ImageTotal"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["ImageOffset"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["VideoTotal"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["VideoOffset"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["NewsTotal"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["NewsOffset"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["SpellingSuggestionsTotal"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["AlteredQuery"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["AlterationOverrideQuery"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["Web"]=>
        array(4) {
          [0]=>
          array(6) {
            ["__metadata"]=>
            array(2) {
              ["uri"]=>
              string(144) "https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Bing/Search/ExpandableSearchResultSet(guid\u00275afc1ab9-f4a7-43e1-9d14-dbec42f83c0c\u0027)/Web?=0&=1"
              ["type"]=>
              string(9) "WebResult"
            }
            ["ID"]=>
            string(36) "38cc61c8-4ce2-4013-92ee-a2fa4de3abcc"
            ["Title"]=>
            string(58) "apache 2.2.21 exploits - Page 2 - Code Exploits Collection"
            ["Description"]=>
            string(257) "... script\u003e password_verify "\u003e\u003cscript\u003ealert(2);\u003c/script\u003e firstname "\u003e\u003cî€€script\u003ealert(3);\u003c/scriptî€ ... 703F67657470776E65643D: Administrators\u003c/î€€a\u003e\u003cimg srcî€="http://192.168.0.15/learn ..."
            ["DisplayUrl"]=>
            string(45) "exploitsdownload.com/search/apache%202.2.21/2"
            ["Url"]=>
            string(52) "http://exploitsdownload.com/search/apache%202.2.21/2"
          }
          [1]=>
          array(6) {
            ["__metadata"]=>
            array(2) {
              ["uri"]=>
              string(144) "https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Bing/Search/ExpandableSearchResultSet(guid\u00275afc1ab9-f4a7-43e1-9d14-dbec42f83c0c\u0027)/Web?=1&=1"
              ["type"]=>
              string(9) "WebResult"
            }
            ["ID"]=>
            string(36) "df1b6d37-efc1-4d3c-bed5-7d6e34a3d686"
            ["Title"]=>
            string(54) "siteniz iÃ§in htlm kodlarÄ± - Sayfa 3 - Baktabul Forum"
            ["Description"]=>
            string(326) "... gelecek ve sooon") \u003c/script\u003e \u003cscript\u003e alert("4!!") \u003c/script\u003e \u003cî€€script\u003e alert("3!!!") \u003c/scriptî€\u003e \u003cscript\u003e ... BURAYA YAZIN!!!\u0027,500,300); return false" \u003e \u003e\u003e\u003eGÄ°RÄ°Åž \u003c\u003c\u003c\u003c\u003c/î€€a\u003e \u003cIMG SRCî€= "http ..."
            ["DisplayUrl"]=>
            string(65) "www.baktabul.net/webmaster/42351-siteniz-icin-htlm-kodlari-3.html"
            ["Url"]=>
            string(72) "http://www.baktabul.net/webmaster/42351-siteniz-icin-htlm-kodlari-3.html"
          }
          [2]=>
          array(6) {
            ["__metadata"]=>
            array(2) {
              ["uri"]=>
              string(144) "https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Bing/Search/ExpandableSearchResultSet(guid\u00275afc1ab9-f4a7-43e1-9d14-dbec42f83c0c\u0027)/Web?=2&=1"
              ["type"]=>
              string(9) "WebResult"
            }
            ["ID"]=>
            string(36) "fab98f52-bbe6-40f7-805d-5ab14b503827"
            ["Title"]=>
            string(55) "php 5.2.17 exploits - Page 1 - Code Exploits Collection"
            ["Description"]=>
            string(228) "... trace_results.php?product_id=117&amp;project_id=40&amp;funder=31"\u003e\u003cî€€script\u003ealert(3);\u003c/scriptî€ ... 703F67657470776E65643D: Administrators\u003c/î€€a\u003e\u003cimg srcî€="http://192.168.0.15/learn ..."
            ["DisplayUrl"]=>
            string(40) "exploitsdownload.com/search/php%205.2.17"
            ["Url"]=>
            string(48) "http://exploitsdownload.com/search/php%205.2.17/"
          }
          [3]=>
          array(6) {
            ["__metadata"]=>
            array(2) {
              ["uri"]=>
              string(144) "https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Bing/Search/ExpandableSearchResultSet(guid\u00275afc1ab9-f4a7-43e1-9d14-dbec42f83c0c\u0027)/Web?=3&=1"
              ["type"]=>
              string(9) "WebResult"
            }
            ["ID"]=>
            string(36) "82b3c849-4cdc-409a-95a8-a74310b723aa"
            ["Title"]=>
            string(102) "DEV ARÅžÄ°V \u0027\u0027HazÄ±r kodlar\u0027Ä±n %90 burada\u0027\u0027 Ä°Ã§eri buyrun\u003e\u003e\u003e"
            ["Description"]=>
            string(283) "... ve sooon")\u003c/script\u003e \u003cscript\u003ealert("4!!")\u003c/script\u003e \u003cî€€script\u003ealert("3!!!")\u003c/scriptî€ ... BURAYA YAZIN!!!\u0027,500,300); return false"\u003e\u003e\u003e\u003eGÄ°RÄ°Åž\u003c\u003c\u003c\u003c\u003c/î€€a\u003e\u003cIMG SRCî€="http ..."
            ["DisplayUrl"]=>
            string(67) "www.zevkli.org/dev-ar350304v-haz305r-kodlar305n-90-burada-304231..."
            ["Url"]=>
            string(100) "http://www.zevkli.org/dev-ar350304v-haz305r-kodlar305n-90-burada-304231eri-buyrungtgtgt-t180384.html"
          }
        }
        ["Image"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
        ["Video"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
        ["News"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
        ["RelatedSearch"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
        ["SpellingSuggestions"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This result is obtained with this custom function:

```
function json_decoder($json) {
    $comment = false;
    $out = '$x=';

    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($json); $i++) {
        if (!$comment) {
            if (($json[$i] == '{') || ($json[$i] == '['))
                $out .= ' array(';
            else if (($json[$i] == '}') || ($json[$i] == ']'))
                $out .= ')';
            else if ($json[$i] == ':')
                $out .= '=>';
            else
                $out .= $json[$i];
        } else
            $out .= $json[$i];
        if ($json[$i] == '"' && $json[($i - 1)] != "\\")
            $comment = !$comment;
    }

    eval($out . ';');
    return $x;
}
```

But I want to use php json_decode function not a custom one.... Any suggestion?

Comment: Why would you expect `\u` encoded characters not decoded?

Comment: `\u003c` is another way to encode `<` in a JSON string. It is 100% equivalent, and should be converted when decoding. If you want it to decode to `\u003c` you need to escape the backslash. I.e. `\\u003c`